# Bad Jump Destination error

Tags: solidity, modifiers, bad-jump, payable

I wrote what I thought was a dead simple contract - a saving jar... you add value ("save") into the jar and when the balance of the contract reaches a certain amount ("target"), then I am able to withdraw the value.
But whenever I try to send it value, it errors with "Bad Jump Destination"

Here is my contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract jar {
  uint public target;
  uint public numDonations;

  function jar (uint _target) {
    target = _target;
    numDonations = 0;
  }

  function save() {
    numDonations++;
  }

  function getBalance() constant returns (uint) {
    return this.balance;
  }

  function withdraw () {
     if (this.balance < target) throw;
     if (!msg.sender.send(this.balance)) throw;
  }
}
```

And here is the save command I am sending:

```
jar.save({from:eth.accounts[0], value: 100000000000000000, gas:3000000})
```

Here is an example of a failed transaction:

https://testnet.etherscan.io/tx/0xcf93aa967f6d1d42b84147511ab58a66a468ee8a102a8d78f78f071ec1a30a05

I have never seen this error before and I am totally stumped. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While you are using Solidity 0.4 you should define your payable function. if your contract will receive Etheres define in your code payable fallback:

```
function() payable {}
```

if you want any functions will accept Ethers it should be declared with a *payable* modifier

```
function save() payable {
    numDonations++;
  }
```

Comment: In particular, for this example, it should be `function save() payable{...}`